# Standalone program using Matlab(GUI) and Arduino

Tags: arduino, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

I have built a matlab code with gui. It is connected to arduino. it works well on the matlab environment. but when i try to make a standalone program using deploytool, the program(gui) opens but it can not connect to arduino. matlab runtime is installed.

error messages:

```
Undefined function or variable 'registerrealtimecataloglocation'.

Error in arduinoio.internal.BaseClass (line 32)
```

Error in arduino

```
Error in connection_trial>Con_Callback (line 142)


Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)


Error in connection_trial (line 43)


Error in matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)connection_trial('Con_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

Comment: We can't help if you don't post your code (see [mcve])

Comment: google the error message and you'll end up here: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/345095 where a MathWorks employee explains that this is due to some unsupported things. If MathWorks does not provide a solution to this problem it is quite unlikely anyone on stackoverflow will

Answer (score 0):

to connect to Arduino through matlab , needs
- com port of Arduino
- uart.. or baud rate
- matlab statement: serConn = serial('Arduino com port here', 'TimeOut', 1, 'BaudRate', 9600);
- fopen(serConn);
- str=char(fread(serConn));

str will receive data from Arduino in case if arduino print in serial any data